# averaging subsets within a data frame while retaining comments

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame, `data` That contains multiple sites, indicated by integer site codes. Within those sites are samples from multiple horizons, `A`,`B` and `C`, which have observations of some type, indicated in the column `value`:

```
site<- c(12,12,12,12,45,45,45,45)
horizon<-c('A','A','B','C','A','A','B','C')
value<- c(19,14,3,2,18,19,4,5)
comment<- c('pizza','pizza','pizza','pizza','taco','taco','taco','taco')
data<- data.frame(site,horizon,value,comment)
```

Which looks like this:

```
  site horizon value comment
1   12       A    19   pizza
2   12       A    14   pizza
3   12       B     3   pizza
4   12       C     2   pizza
5   45       A    18    taco
6   45       A    19    taco
7   45       B     4    taco
8   45       C     5    taco
```

In this case both sites have multiple `A` observations. I would like to average the values of of duplicate horizons within a site. I would like to retain the comment line within the data frame as well. All observations within a site have the same entry within the comment vector. I would like the output to look like this:

```
  site horizon value comment
1   12       A  16.5   pizza
3   12       B     3   pizza
4   12       C     2   pizza
5   45       A  18.5    taco
7   45       B     4    taco
8   45       C     5    taco
```

Comment: With dplyr, this works: `data %>% group_by(site,horizon,comment) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`, though you should have 16.5 not 18.5 in the first row, eh?

Comment: @Frank thanks! Is there any way to have dplyr do this without specifying the comment vector. My real data set has many many comment vectors.

Comment: Hm, you could do `data %>% group_by_(.dots=setdiff(names(.),"value")) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`. Personally, I would just keep the `comment` data in a separate table if it's determined by `site`.

Comment: @frank good point. I think I'm going to go that route actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'  site horizon value comment
1   12       A    19   pizza
2   12       A    14   pizza
3   12       B     3   pizza
4   12       C     2   pizza
5   45       A    18    taco
6   45       A    19    taco
7   45       B     4    taco
8   45       C     5    taco')
merge(aggregate(value ~ site+horizon, FUN=mean, data=d), unique(d[,-3]))
```